# Getting posts from multiple users?

Tags: posts, loop, author

Using a third party plugin that allows users to follow each other, we can retrieve the users being followed like so (commented):-

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php global $userpro_social;

        $following = $userpro_social->following( get_current_user_id() ); //get users the current user is following
        print_r($following) ?> // print the array so we can see who we're following


        <?php $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1; ?>     
        <?php query_posts( array( 'author'=> ??? , 'paged' => $paged, ) ); ?>      

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>


            <?php if ( has_post_format( 'video' )) {
                    get_template_part( 'video-post' );
                }elseif ( has_post_format( 'image' )) {
                    get_template_part( 'image-post' );
                } else {
                   get_template_part( 'standard-post' );
                }

            ?>

        <?php endwhile;?>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

So this would output something like this

Array
(
    [24] => 1
    [1] => 1
)

ie, we're following users with the ID of 1 and 24, simple enough?

The part I'm lost on is this

```
<?php query_posts( array( 'author'=> ??? , 'paged' => $paged, ) ); ?>
```

How do I actually output posts from those users, it's already stored in the array so I think it should be easy enough, but I just can't figure it out even after reading the codex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I suggest don't use `query_posts`.
(No one is really a WPSE user if had no read [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/35541)).

So you can use `WP_Query` with [`author__in` parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters) in combination with [`array_keys`](http://www.php.net/array_keys) PHP function.

```
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;    

$query = new WP_Query(
  array( 'author__in' => array_keys( $following ), 'paged' => $paged )
);

while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
  // your loop here
endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

---

*PS: you don't need to open and close php tags on every line.*

Comment: Great answer, thanks. The reason I'm use query_posts and not WP_query is because I'm using infinite scroll plugin, that doesn't accept WP_query arrays, so the easiest thing to do is modify the main query with query_posts.